# Figure with subfigures containing text and a drawing

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am trying to do something similar to this [image: What I am trying to achieve] but I have no idea on how to do it. Usually when I add figures i use the \begin{figure}, the problem is that I have no idea on how to achieve this result. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: You still can use figure, along with subcaption form the `subcaption` package (or alternatively `subfig`). The environment just changes the counter, you can put in whatever you want. Instead of a picture/graphic you can put a minipage or a tikzpicture.

Comment: If you provide all the contents in form of copy/pastable code [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html), maybe you are lucky and someone will do it in his/her spare time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that now! That's the first time I don't do "image" graphics. @Johannes_B: I am not really aiming at that, I just want to know how to start to create that myself, but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `subcaption`, `tikz-cd` for the diagram and `makecell` for easy multi-line cells in a tabular environment:

```
        \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}
        \usepackage{sansmathfonts} 

        \usepackage{caption, subcaption} 
        \usepackage{makecell}
        \usepackage{tikz-cd}
        \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
        \tikzset{%
        commutative diagrams/.cd,
        arrow style=tikz,
        diagrams={>= triangle 45, line width=2*tikzcdrule}
        }%

        \begin{document}

        \begin{figure}[!h]
          \centering\sffamily\bfseries\boldmath
          \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont = sf}
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
               \renewcommand{\cellalign}{rt}\renewcommand{\cellgape}{\Gape[4pt]}
                \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                      A & \makecell{eff : \\ dur :} & \makecell[l]{P \\ 1} \\
                      B & \makecell{eff : \\ dur :} & \makecell[l]{Q \\ 2}  \\
                      C & \makecell{pref :  \\ eff : \\dur : } & \makecell[l]{P,  Q \\ R \\ 2}
                    \end{tabular}
                    \caption{}\label{fig: 1a}
          \end{subfigure}
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                    $ \begin{tikzcd}[row sep = scriptsize]
                        A_{[0} \rar & P_{\mkern 2mu [1}\arrow{ddl} \\
                          B_{[0} \rar & Q_{[2} \dlar \\
                          C_{[2} \rar & R_{[5}
                        \end{tikzcd} $\vspace{-4.3pt}
                    \caption{}\label{fig: 1b}
          \end{subfigure}
          \caption{A figure}\label{fig1}
        \end{figure}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use minipages like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{image1.jpg}
    \caption{Caption 1}
    \label{label1}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{image2.jpg}
    \caption{Caption 2}
    \label{label2}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Joint caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which results in this:
[image: result]